# speex_encode_int() always returns 70 encoded ouput bytes

Tags: c, speex

I'd like to encode data with libspeex. However, `speex_encode_int()`
 always returns a `SpeexBits` of length 70. It doesn't matter what I provide (music, silence, voice).

Input specification: 16bit, PCM, Mono, 44100Hz sampling rate, LE

```
int tmp;
short *input = ...; // input data (PCM, 16bit)
int inputFrames = ...; // number of frames
void *state;
SpeexBits bits;
int frameSize;
int bufferLength;
void* output = NULL;
int outputLength = 0;
int i;

state = speex_encoder_init(&speex_wb_mode);
tmp = 8;
speex_encoder_ctl(state, SPEEX_SET_QUALITY, &tmp);
speex_encoder_ctl(state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &frameSize);
tmp = 44100;
speex_encoder_ctl(state, SPEEX_SET_SAMPLING_RATE, &tmp);
speex_bits_init(&bits);


for(i = 0; i < (inputFrames / frameSize); i++){
    speex_bits_reset(&bits);
    speex_encode_int(state, &input[i * frameSize], &bits);
    bufferLength = speex_bits_nbytes(&bits);
    output = realloc(output, outputLength + bufferLength);
    speex_bits_write(&bits, (char*)(output + outputLength), bufferLength);
    outputLength += bufferLength;
}

// process output data    

free(output);
free(input);
```

Did I make an error in my encoding routine? Or is there anything wrong with my initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're using quality 8, which is 27.8 kb/s for wideband, which rounded up is 70 bytes/frame. I'm not sure what you expect. Changing the quality parameter should give you more bytes or fewer bytes (depending on the value you choose). Also, using 44.1 kHz is *not* recommended. You should use wideband (16 kHz). Alternatively, you can have a look at the Opus codec.